# help with make file

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a make file like this....... some of the files are in the main directory and some others in the tests directory..

```
VPATH = tests

objects = main.o script.o factory.o serve.o enter.o\
           login.o notify.o check.o
script : $(objects)
    g++ $(objects) -lcurl -o script

main.o : script.h
script.o : enter.h login.h factory.h
factory.o : check.h notify.h serve.h
check.o :
serve.o : check.h
notify.o :
enter.o : check.h
login.o : check.h

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm *.o script
```

i want make to save the object files to the directory where its cpp file comes from.. i.e. if script.cpp was inside tests folder, then i want the script.o also tobe inside the tests folder.. now it just saves the file inside the main folder..

Thanks in advance..

EDIT 1:
      I need to add files lateron to the tests folder.. is there a way to make the makefile recognise that new files have been added and compile them also?

Comment: Is using VPATH essential for you? If you just explicitly prefix tests/ to the appropriate object file names, things should just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding a list of files to build, you can use a wildcard to find source files.  You can also use a substitution to convert this into a list of object files.  Provide a generic rule for building a .c into a .o and you should be all set.

```
FILES_TO_BUILD := $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard tests\*.c)
OBJECTS_FILES  := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(FILES_TO_BUILD))

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(COPTS) $^ # or whatever your compiler line is

script: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    g++ $^ -lcurl -o $@
```

I haven't tested this makefile (it's just off the top of my head) but it should give you something to start with.

Comment: Granted, this makefile doesn't account for the header file dependencies.  Given how few files are in the example project, it's probably easiest to use `HEADERS := $(wildcard *.h)` to locate all of the header files and use `%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)` for your generic target to make everything dependent on everything else.  You will have to rebuild everything if anything changes, but with only 14 files a full rebuild shouldn't be too bad.  If you had a larger project, though, you'd probably want a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like

```
 mv *.d $(VPATH)/
```

in your makefile, to be something like:

```
...
script : $(objects)
    g++ $(objects) -lcurl -o script
    mv *.d $(VPATH)/
...
```

You may need to add **@** in front of **mv**, "**@mv...**"